# Bootstrap clear space

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want clear space form my HTML code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <img src="~/Content/assets/images/male.jpg" style="height:35px;" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <p class="pull-left text-primary text-capitalize text-weight-bold">Deneme</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: In the first case, col-xs-1 is bigger than img. In the second case, i dont know. Can you show the complete code?

Comment: if from clear you mean image don't be over below div you can clear style="height:35px;" or set height for first row,if you could tell me what you mean from clearing I can help you more –

Comment: do u have your code in jsfiddle=

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible because the space between the user image and the username is default by the bootstrap grid system.

By the way, you have a col-xs-1 and a col-md-10 in one row, I don't know for sure if that is 100% right...